# How do I make java sockets work? So confused

Tags: java, sockets

This is the code for my server, its supposed to take an input from the user, print it into console, then send it back to the user.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class DateServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(10219);

        Socket s = listener.accept();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        out.println("connected");
        out.flush();

        System.out.println("connected");
        String test;

        while (true) {
            try {
                test = input.readLine();
                System.out.println(test);
                out.println(test + " is what I recieved"); 
                out.flush();
            } catch(Exception X) {System.out.println(X);}
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;   
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;

public class DateClient {
    public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Enter IP Address of a machine that is");
        System.out.println("running the date service on port 10219:");
        String serverAddress = keyboard.next();
        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 10219);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));      
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println(input.readLine());
        while(true){
            try{
                System.out.println(input.readLine());
                out.println(keyboard.next());
                out.flush();
            } catch(Exception X){System.out.println(X);}
        }
    }
}
```

This was designed to work across a LAN network. I have no idea why it doesn't work, all that happens is the client will get the message "connected" and nothing else will happen, no matter what is typed into the client end. I'm a noob when it comes to java, but after a bunch of googling and searching through the java libraries, I can't seem to make it work. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You send one line from the server to the client, but in your client you wait for two lines before accepting user input to be sent to the server.

Bearing in mind that `input.readLine()` will block until data is received, can you spot the [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) here:

Server:

```
out.println("connected");

while (true) {
    try {
        input.readLine();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
input.readLine();
while(true) {
    try {
        input.readLine();
        out.println(keyboard.next());
    }
}
```

(extraneous code trimmed away to show just the problematic sequence of statements)

Answer (score 0):

Both your client and server mutually wait for each other trying to do `input.readLine()`.

This can be easily seen if you remove server's `out.println("connected")` and its corresponding client's first `input.readLine()`.

On the client, you should probably write *first* and only then read the response. Try reordering the following lines:

```
System.out.println(input.readLine());
out.println(keyboard.next());
out.flush();
```

to get

```
out.println(keyboard.next());
out.flush();
System.out.println(input.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the client, try changing

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
System.out.println(input.readLine());
while(true){
    try{
        System.out.println(input.readLine());
        out.println(keyboard.next());
        out.flush();
    } catch(Exception X){System.out.println(X);}
}
```

to

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
while(true){
    try{
        System.out.println(input.readLine());
        out.println(keyboard.nextLine());
        out.flush();
    } catch(Exception X){System.out.println(X);}
}
```

Your client is trying to read two lines, but your server sends just one, then polls for input, so both are locked. Also, sinc your server is reading line-by-line, your client should be sending data line-by-line.